# Android 5+(lollipop ) Issues on playing video from URL

Tags: video-streaming, android-5.0-lollipop, android-video-player, android-videoview

I have video URL and i want to play that in to my application. We are using video view to play. It's played with out any issues in all other device but when i try with lollipop updated device it take too much of time for prepared and play for few seconds then it stop with ANR alert.

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(Activity);
            progressVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoView.start();
        }
    });

    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("Error", "------>error"+what+"/"+extra);
            if (extra != 0) {
                Utilities.showToast(ViewVlipActivity.this,
                        "Sorry, This video cannot be played.");
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        }

    });
```

Above is the code we used to play video.

**Additional information:** Video is mp4 it has encoded with H.264 video codec

Comment: I am facing problem with all nexus devices to stream videos in video view. For device having lollipop without nexus, it is playing. I just need to know reason why video view is not able to play stream after upgrading to lollipop.

Comment: I have checked with the moto g same issue. I have posted this bug in to lot of forum but i cant get any solution for that. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it works for me:

```
videoUrl= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(videoUrl, "UTF-8");
Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
```